# How to update redhat from 7.1 to 7.3

Tags: rhel, upgrade

In an attempt to install a specific piece software and do what the requirements ask, I should upgrade RedHat from **7.1 to 7.3**. I Googled it, but I didn't find a sure answer.
I can use yum like:

```
yum upgrade
```

but I'm not sure if it will work. The idea is to force RedHat to do the update specifically to a 7.3, not just any version.
Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In order to update, you will need to have your system registered to Red Hat's Customer Portal. I'm assuming you've done that already, since you mention `yum upgrade`.

On the hosted update server, you cannot lock in a specific version (for example, 7.3), you can only upgrade to the "latest available". Since 7.4 is now available, you can update your system to 7.4 by simply running `yum update`. That will update all your packages to the latest available for 7.x, which will happen to be 7.4 plus any updates to the 7.4 release.

If you need to upgrade to specifically 7.3, you need to have a different repository available that has only 7.3 packages. This can be accomplished by either rolling your own repository or by making use of Red Hat Satellite. There may be other options, but any other options will fall broadly into the "roll your own" category.

Comment: If you MUST have 7.3 versions of software, you could also pay more for EUS licenses for 7.3.x. See here for more details: https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-eus#c6